# sudo, problems with terminal emulator excepting my pass word

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, emulation

i am trying to get my bluetooth working and looked on the forum for answers,what i found, that i thought might work was a command,  sudo apt-get install bluetooth. i typed this into  the terminal emulator, followed by a prompt to enter my pass word, it would not let me put my pass word in,what can i do know ? i am running Bionic Beaver 18.04 on a dell studio inspiron 1557 i have tried several times but keeps asking for pass word,which it will not let me enter,I am using my ubuntu log in pass word,but still the terminal emulator will not allow it!

Comment: Enter your password. Unix does, by tradition, not echo anything back to screen at password prompts. So simply input your password, and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal doesn't show your password, or even any dots while typing. Even though nothing is showing, it is still accepting input from your keyboard. Try carefully typing your password, and pressing enter. If you've entered it correctly, it should begin the command. If not, the terminal will return:
 `Sorry, try again.`

Comment: HI ccoltman151 have tried your suggestion but still not having it, is my command  sudo apt-get install blueman     the correct format? best wishes david stone

Comment: Can you copy and paste what the terminal returns when you type in your password?

Comment: Sorry,try again

Comment: You're not typing the correct password in.